# Cast customView from ID

Tags: android, view, casting, classcastexception

**Question:**

this is my situation:

```
public class customView extends View {
    myView = new RelativeLayout(...);
    //...
    public customView getLayout() {
        return (customView) myView;
    }

    public void myFunction(){}
}
```

then, if I do:

```
customView cv = new customView();
cv.setId(100);
// mainLayout si riferisce alla View principale
mainLayout.addView(cv.getLayout());
```

It returns a ClassCastException in the moment I try to get the new "customView" I maked before.

```
( (custonView) mainLayout.findViewById(100) ).myFunction();
```

It says that I cannot cast a RelativeLayout in customView

My customView rappresent a RelativeLayout with some new function: when I create it, a timer starts in a TextView embed.

When I recall the object, I should be able to stop the timer timer (stop timer function written and fully work).

Thanks everybody

**Answer:**

```
public class customView extends View {
    public void customView(Context context){
        myView = new RelativeLayout(...);
        **addView(myView);**
    }
    //...
    //public customView getLayout() {
    //    return (customView) myView;
    //}

    public void myFunction(){}
}
```

and call It with

```
customView cv = new customView();
cv.setId(100);
//mainLayout si riferisce alla View principale
//mainLayout.addView(cv.getLayout());
mainLayout.addView(cv);
```

Comment: the problem with this line return (customView) myView;
you cannot cast View to RelativeLayout

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to extend `RelativeLayout` in your custom class. Won't it make the whole thing easier for you? You will still be able to add custom logic to it.

The problem in you code, I think, is that you add a `RelativeLayout` to `mainLayout`, you're not adding your own `customView`.

Comment: I tried also to extend RelativeLayout, same exception. I think what you say, but how to add my customView instead RelativeLayout?

Comment: In this case you would be adding your custom RelativeLayout, wouldn't you? I'm not sure that's the problem...